# Call footer block of one theme into another

Tags: magento2, blocks, theme, footer

There are two themes which i am using. One is magento theme 'Smartwave porto' and another is Ced commerce theme which i got for ced commerce extension. This theme is enabled only for this particular extension pages. 
I want to display footer block of my 'Porto theme' into Ced commerce extension theme.
How can i do that. Remember i want to call the footer block from phtml file of ced commerce extension.

Comment: You want to call that footer in cms page or in phtml ?

Comment: @PЯINCƏ In phtml

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this way

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Porto_NameSpace::html/footer.phtml"}}
```

Comment: What should i put in class and template? Did you understand my question?In Porto theme i am calling footer block as <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="footer_block" template="html/footer.phtml">. Do i need to provide same class name and template path in other theme phtml file or something else

Comment: yes you can use like this way

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy it from `Porto theme` to `Ced commerce` example : `footer2.phtml`, then you get it simply like this :

```
<?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template')->setTemplate('Magento_Theme::footer2.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Comment: @Prince getting error Invalid template file: 'Smartwave_Porto::html/footer.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'magento\framework\view\element\template_0'

Comment: In Porto theme i am calling footer block as  <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="footer_block" template="html/footer.phtml">. Do i need to provide same class name and template path in other theme phtml file or something else

Comment: If this footer don't inherits `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` it becomes complicated, try to replace : `createBlock('Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template')` with `createBlock('Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template')`

Comment: @Prince Did that too...but getting error